# Raspberry Pi Wordpress Website + NoIP + Real Domain issur/confusion

Tags: wordpress, raspberry-pi, noip

I'm trying to get a GoDaddy domain to point at my Raspberry Pi Wordpress site.

I've got a website setup on my Raspberry Pi, running locally. I also did the port forwarding on my router. Now because my ip is dynamic, I've setup a No-IP domain (foobar.ddns.net), so now that points to my external IP address (87.112.xxx.xxx), which points to my Rpi (192.168.x.x). I also have a real domain (foobar.co.uk).

My question is: Is there a way to point my REAL domain (foobar.co.uk) to my foobar.ddns.net domain, so that it points to the website on my Raspberry Pi? And if I did that, what do I have to change in my Wordpress settings (site title, etc?), so you can access foobar.co.uk/wp-admin for example?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your REAL domain's configuration (foobar.co.uk) and configure it so the IP address must be your external IP address and add the port 80 which you have forwarded to the Raspberry's local IP.

You must have your local IP static, in order to do that, visit this page and follow the tutorial: https://kerneldriver.wordpress.com/2012/10/21/configuring-wpa2-using-wpa_supplicant-on-the-raspberry-pi/